# Получить Match из Regex

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть `Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<Property>[^:|;]+):(?<Value>[^:|;]+);");`
Как мне получить Match где Property = "Таблица"?
Хотел вот-так но так нельзя:

```
Match match = regex.Match(str).where(b=>b.Groups["Property"] == "Таблица")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Одно первое совпадение:

```
Match match = regex.Matches(str)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .First(m => m.Groups["Property"].Value == "Таблица");
```

Коллекция совпадений:

```
var matches = regex.Matches(str)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(m => m.Groups["Property"].Value == "Таблица");
```

Comment: "MatchCollection" не содержит определение для "AsEnumerable", и наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод расширения "DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(DataTable)" требует наличия получателя типа "DataTable".

Comment: То что Вы написали неработает

Comment: @Qwerty using System.Linq;

Comment: @PashaPash Установлена

Comment: @Qwerty не .net core? в старом фреймворке он просто IEnumerable, нужен .Cast<Match>(). в .net core он IEnumerable<Match>, там и .AsEnumerable() не нужен.

Comment: @Qwerty хватит писать на старье 3-х летней давности :)

Comment: @PashaPash Я пишу на WPF .NET Framework 4.8, это последняя версия, так что о каком старье Вы говорите я не понимаю.

Comment: @Qwerty последняя версия под WPF - .NET 5.0, он же .NET Core 5 - только что проверил, создал пустой проект -  в нем все работает :)

Comment: @PashaPash С Cast сработало спасибо.

Comment: @Qwerty сорри, попутал с Qwertiy, местным модератором, ник уж очень похож )

Comment: @PashaPash Ничего страшно. Я просто пишу на .NET Framework. Так 4.8 это его последняя версия